# Not able to start network on Hyperledger Fabric network V 0.19. Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT Command failed

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

I am trying to setup my first Hyperledger Fabric network on my Windows 10 Pro PC.

I did follow below steps to create network.

> 1. *./startFabric.sh* - Success
> 2. *./createPeerAdminCard.sh*  - Success
> 3. *composer archive create -t dir -n .*   - .bna file created successfully on project root folder
> 4. *composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile sample-test-network@0.0.1.bna*

Now I got error in next step when executing below command for start network.

> *composer network start --networkName diam-test-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file sample-testkAdmin.card*

It take sometime for execution and then it gave error mention below :

> **Processing these Network Admins:
>           userName: admin
>
> × Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
>   Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid
>   responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an
>   error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT Command failed**

When I seen log using below command :

> peer0.org1.example.com .

I attached log error in image file.[Log Image File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdTPG.png)

Can anyone suggest to me how I can proceed next step for start my first Hyper Fabric network?

Comment: Hyperledger Composer is not supported for Windows and there is no automated testing.  So you maybe hitting some specific Windows environmental issues - there is a brief discussion thread on Rocket Chat: https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/composer?msg=xnvcu8Q7FtjGzJam7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following modification in "**docker-compose.yaml**" file and restart Docker-compose by using **docker-compose stop** & **docker-compose -start** command then I **repeat all procedure for create Network** mentioned above and  issue has been resolved.

**- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=compose_default**

To

**- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=tutorial-network_default**

Here "tutorial-network_default" is the network name. You can find your network name by using **"docker network ls"** command